# Why does a ng-show on a LI element allow inner A element to be clicked

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I am using ui-router for navigation.

One of the menu items can be clicked on and off for which I use `ng-show` and a variable.

This works well, however, when the `li` element is hidden, the mouse still turns into a hand and can click the link, in this case, the user can still go to the "testing" page:

`<li ng-show="showTesting"><a href="#testing"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> {{'MENU_TESTING' | translate}}</a></li>`

**How can I make not only the link disappear but be inactive?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-if`

```
<li ng-if="showTesting"><a href="#testing"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> {{'MENU_TESTING' | translate}}</a></li>
```